# MySQL Query issue - Adding additional and totaling

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following query which is design the multiply the total quantity of products, against quantity price and put this into a new column. What I am wondering and a bit stuck with. Is there then a way to also total this new column. So I as well as getting a total for each row ordered, I can also get a total for the order itself.

```
SELECT Product_Quantity, ProductPrice, (Product_Quantity*ProductPrice) as   Total FROM Order_Info WHERE Order_Number = '1'
```

Comment: Do you mean the total from the entire column?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, yes mate.

Comment: You can use ROLLUP, but I'd probably do the grand total in application code

Comment: Hi Strawberry, thank you. I am considering doing it in the application code. I am unfamilar with the ROLLUP command, is it possible you could show me this?

Comment: You could look into this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Answer (score 2):

This add a record with a total.
Simulates GROUP BY with ROLLUP

```
SELECT
  Product_Quantity
, ProductPrice
, (Product_Quantity*ProductPrice) AS Total
FROM
 Order_Info
WHERE
 Order_Number = '1'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  NULL
, NULL
, SUM((Product_Quantity*ProductPrice)) AS Total
FROM
 Order_Info
WHERE
 Order_Number = '1'
```

Comment: Cool Awesome guys. I have ended up totaling the column on the application side (PHP). Appreciate all your help .

Answer (score 1):

To get a summary row, you can use sql's `union` and the `sum` aggregating function. Try this:

```
SELECT Product_Quantity, ProductPrice, (Product_Quantity*ProductPrice) as   Total FROM Order_Info WHERE Order_Number = '1'
union all
SELECT sum(Product_Quantity), sum(ProductPrice), sum(Product_Quantity*ProductPrice) as   Total FROM Order_Info WHERE Order_Number = '1'
```